# Is this an affine variety in $\Bbb R^2$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the [affine variety](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~gm/teaching/MATH32062/theorems.pdf) $V\subset \Bbb R^2$ defined by $x^2+y^2=1$. We set

$$X=V\setminus \{(x_0,y_0)\},$$

where $x_0^2+y_0^2=1$. Is $X$ an affine variety in $\Bbb R^2$?

If not, then,  set difference of two affine varieties need not be an affine variety.

Comment: An affine variety is a zero locus of a collection of polynomials, thus is closed.

Comment: @John Thanks a lot! How to prove your statement?

Comment: @ziangchen The Zariski topology is much coarser than the Euclidean topology (the zero set of a polynomial is closed in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$). Is $X$ closed in the Euclidean topology?

Comment: @John: not so fast! "Affine" means "isomorphic to a closed affine set", which is an isomorphism-invariant property, whereas "closed" is not. The simplest example: $\mathbf{A}^1 \setminus \{0\}$ is obviously not closed in $\mathbf{A}^1$, but it's still affine!

Comment: In his question, I thought he is asking whether $X$ is affine as subvariety in $\mathbb R^2$ ^^.

Comment: Yes, the wording isn't completely clear. If the question is "is this a closed affine set in $\mathbf{R}^2$?" then your argument shows the answer is certainly _no_. If, however, the question is "Is $X$ is an affine variety?", then I claim the answer is _yes_.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Did you read the link the OP gave? I'm pretty sure, for him, he means is it an algebraic set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I guess we need to wait for his response though.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: yes, let's see what the OP says. Unfortunately, the definition of affine variety in the linked material is pretty misleading.

Comment: @Alex Youcis  yes.  I am a algebraic geometry beginner

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Misleading? I don't know if I agree with that. It's also the definition books such as Hartshorne adopt, before they later redefine it to mean the normal ringed space definition.

Comment: @ziangchen So, can you tell us which you meant? Did you just mean to ask whether the set you wrote is closed in the Zariski topology?

Comment: @Alex Youcis  I have just learned the definition of affine variety, and try to find a  counterexample to show that set difference of two affine varieties need not be an affine variety.

Comment: @ziangchen How are you DEFINING an affine variety? Do you mean it to be the first definition in the above link? The solution set to some polynomial defined on the ambient space?

Comment: @AlexYoucis: curious, I hadn't ever read that part of Hartshorne before. By contrast, Shafarevich is careful to distinguish between "closed affine sets" and "affine varieties", with the latter being defined in an isomorphism-invariant way. The Shafarevich version is more sensible to me, because of the example I wrote above, but I guess different people have different opinions. Live and learn!

Comment: @Alex Youcis "The solution set to some polynomial defined on the affine space". But You can do a comprehensive discussion

Comment: @ziangchen Read what John and I said above. Any set which is the solution set to a polynomial equation, is closed in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is your set?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Yes. Thank you very very much

Comment: I have read other counterexample, such as $\{(r,r):r\in \Bbb R, r\ne0\}\subset \Bbb R^2$, but the proof (from books) is complicated